# Mongoose asynchronous schema validation is not working

Tags: mongoose

I have the following code which validates my "timezone" field:

```
orgSchema.path('timezone').validate(function(value) {
  return Timezone.findOne({_id: value}, "_id", function (err, timezone) { return false; });
}, "Please provide a valid timezone");
```

The field is always passing, even when I add a "return false" in the innermost function.  I know that I am missing a callback somewhere - I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An [asynchronous validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) needs to accept a second parameter that's the callback it must call to deliver the boolean result of the validation.

```js
orgSchema.path('timezone').validate(function(value, callback) {
  return Timezone.findOne({_id: value}, "_id", function (err, timezone) { 
    callback(timezone != null);
  });
}, "Please provide a valid timezone");
```