# Mongoose custom validator: check if value exists in database

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am currently trying to add a custom validator to my schema. For some reason I cannot query the database. Does anyone know a solution for my problem?

This is the schema:

```
var Portfolio = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Title is required']
    },
    thumbnail: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Thumbnail is required'],
    },
    description: String,
    date: Date,
    images: [String],
    categories: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    order: Number,
    slug: {
        type: String,
        validate: {
            validator: slugExists,
            message: 'Slug already exists, choose a different title',
        }
    }
}, options);
```

This is the method that checks whether the data exists:

```
function slugExists(value) {
    this.model.count({slug: value}, function(err, count) {
        if (error) {
            return err;
        }
        return count > 0;
    });
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: this.model.count is not a function
```

I have also tried to use the following:

```
mongoose.model['portfolio'].count(...)
```

but the result is the same.

I have been trying to fix the problem for two hours now, even tried different approaches (for example the pre hook). But adding the custom validation directly to the Schema feels like the cleanest entry.

Hope you have a solution for me. Many thanks in advance!

Jeffrey

Comment: Hm... why not just add a `unique` index on `slug`? Nonetheless, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271900/1022914) might guide you somewhere. Have you tried `mongoose.model('portfolio').count(...)` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mikey. Sadly both solutions doesn't work. I keep receiving the following error: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Can use the `pre-save` method 
Consider the example below where trying to validate username in user model  :

```
   UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
   var self = this;
   mongoose.models["User"].findOne({username: self.username}, function (err, user) {
      if (!user) {
          next();
      } else {
          next(new Error("Username already exists!"));
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for coming up with a solution. I don't feel like using the pre hook though, because then I have to think of another way to handle the error messages (as you can see in my example, I am using Mongoose's custom messages for the errors).

Comment: By using above also you an get the same custom errors. Also you can use the hook function in your custom function.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Eventually I found the solution I was looking for. Still I am curious how you can build the same custom errors within the pre hooks. I will be looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

While I was testing the different solutions I found a post that answered my question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26268156/8267696).

This was the solution I was looking for:

```
function slugExists(value, callback) {
    this.constructor.count({slug: value}, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        }
        callback(count === 0);
    });
}

Portfolio.pre('validate', function(next) {
    this.slug = slugify(this.title);
    next();
});
```

Side note: The slug will be generated based on the title. That is why I had to use a 'validate' pre hook so that the slug is already set before validation (otherwise the validator would be ignored, because it doesn't have any value and it's not required)